# Android autocomplete background color for EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, autocomplete, android-edittext

I notice some Android phones have the autocomplete / auto-insert for inserting the login credentials. See Image:

[image]

My question is, can I change this Yellow background color to another?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the folowing attribute in your appTheme - v26

```
<item name="android:autofilledHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Comment: Do you know analogue for api less than 23?